# Multi step form with jQuery which degrades nicely if JS is turned off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently had my form set up so that each section was refreshed using Ajax, however it didn’t degrade gracefully with JavaScript turned off and I’ve looked into putting each part of the form in to a separate view which works fine but isn’t that great to be honest.

I know the client wants it to look nice so I thought about using jQuery to show and hide forms, so if JavaScript is turned off then all of the forms build in to one long form.  However the only problem I am facing is that after each section the user needs to submit this information for it to be validated before the next stage is completed.  How can I do this if JavaScript is turned off because the other forms will be visible...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using one long form divided into sections, and then if JavaScript is enabled you hide all but one section at a time, providing navigation between the sections (via [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), for instance).

Alternately, you could look at using `script` and `noscript` sections, but then you end up duplicating the form (once in the `script` sections, once in the `noscript` sections) and it starts getting to be a maintenance problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you do wrong is that you're thinking reverse. When you have it working with javascript disabled then it's much easier to apply some javascript functionality.

In addition to that I would display different forms based on wich step in the process the user are. And to that form pass the values from the last step into hidden fields. That way you can have a "step"-registration without js enabled.

?step=1 and let say you use php `<?php if (isset($_GET['step']) && $_GET['step'] == '1'): ?>`

Then just reload the part that contains the form with ajax.