# RoadMap(?) UI in jQuery/ asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, user-interface, asp.net-webcontrol

Do we have any roadMap UI in jQuery or asp.net

I am not sure about the UI name but the UI will look like [image]

I have seen the same kind of UI in SAP where every step will be highlightened in the complete process

Comment: This is called a flowchart typically.  Here's a SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944723/javascript-flowchart-flow-diagram-lib

Comment: please look at this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192945/multi-step-form-with-jquery-which-degrades-nicely-if-js-is-turned-off]

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot yes using tabs we can achieve this process partially but still  the arrow between each step will be missing?

Comment: the arrow is only a CSS detail you can make background to show arrows.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this referred to as a *Progress Tracker*: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/15/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/.  I don't know if that's a widely used term or just something they came up with.

I remember looking for something like this a while back don't remember coming across anything that was plug and play.  Closest I've seen are:

- In jQuery there's http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx.  Demo at: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/webform_to_wizard/
- If you prefer to work with asp.net controls, http://weblogs.asp.net/grantbarrington/archive/2009/08/11/styling-the-asp-net-wizard-control-to-have-the-steps-across-the-top.aspx shows you how to put the wizard steps at the top.

Either way, you'd need to come up with some imagery/css for arrows.  The smashing magazine link should have some examples to help with that.